# How to move QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

How to move `QListWidgetItem` and do not miss Item widget?

This works when drag & drop but can't do the same job on button.

Comment: what do you mean with move? like up and down in the list? what do you mean with missing an item widget?

Comment: As far as I understand it he is able to move the item with drag&drop but he also wants to move it with the push of a button. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes I didn't find any mechanism how to move QListWidgetItem Up and Down with item widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
removeItemWidget( item(row) );
QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents (p_widget,QEvent::DeferredDelete );
```

I remove widget which is shown in Item and make a patch in the way that remove delete signal from queue. in this way I can move Widget to another item

```
int DropList::moveWidget(int row, int pos)
{
    const int new_row  = row+pos;
    if(count()>1 && row>=0 && row <count() && new_row>=0 && new_row<count())
    {
        // A->B
        DropListItem *pA = widgetByRow(row);
        DropListItem *pB = widgetByRow(new_row);
        if(pB->isMovable() && pA->isMovable())
        {

            removeItemWidget(item(new_row));
            removeItemWidget(item(row));
            QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents (pB,QEvent::DeferredDelete );
            QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents (pA,QEvent::DeferredDelete );
            setItemWidget(item(new_row),pA);
            setItemWidget(item(row),pB);
        }
        emit changed();
        return new_row;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

parameters are row - is an item **row** and **pos** +1, +2 ,-1 ,....